# How can I activate the "Track changes" feature in Visual Studio's Text Editor when its setting is greyed out?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, text-editor

The track changes feature currently is not active in my VS. When I edit a cs file, there is no bar indicating changes.

The setting "Track Changes" is perfectly uninformative: a greyed out, checked checkbox. What the hell do I learn from that?

I use the Microsoft Git provider, maybe that matters.

Anyone has an idea how I can turn on track changes?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you disable the **Selection margin** option, the **Track changes** option will be disabled automatically. This is intended behaviour since the selection margin is the area to the left of the code which is used to show tracked changes.

[image]